# Displaying multiple copies of one activerecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, pg

I am displaying a list of articles and using will_paginate gem and endless scrolling. This is all working fine.

My problem, however, is that I am occasionally getting multiple copies of the same article in the view. It doesn't happen all the time, and nor with every article, but enough that it is bloody annoying.

I know there is no duplication in the database, and so the problem occurs in the rendering somehow.

Here is my controller:

```
@articles = Article.order("date_published DESC", "RANDOM()").paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10)
```

I am trying somehow to include the distinct or uniq method, but it seems I can't use either with the order method.

I am using pg for db.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stop randomizing them?

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks! I didn't realize that random ordering had that effect.

Comment: Look at my answer, and when you perform a task like that you should really think about what you're code is going to do. What effect will it have on the result. Why were you ordering by "RANDOM()" to begin with?

Comment: I was ordering by date, and then randomly ordering within each day. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises with your sub-sort, `RANDOM()`.

Imagine I have these posts:

```
id  published  title
----------------------
 1  1/1/1970   One
 2  1/2/1970   Two
 3  1/2/1970   Three
 4  1/3/1970   Four
```

If I request page one (with a page size of 2), I can either get 4 and 3, or 4 and 2. Now, if I request page 2 I can either get 3 and 1 or 2 and 1. This is because of the `RANDOM()` sub-sort. The first query may pull the page from this result:

```
id  published  title
----------------------
 4  1/3/1970   Four
 3  1/2/1970   Three
 2  1/2/1970   Two
 1  1/1/1970   One
```

Which is 4 and 3, but this result is also possible:

```
id  published  title
----------------------
 4  1/3/1970   Four
 2  1/2/1970   Two
 3  1/2/1970   Three
 1  1/1/1970   One
```

Which is 4 and 2. And either of these results will also result in a different page 2 as well. This random sort is the cause of your duplicates, you need to use consistent sorts or manage removal of duplicates in some other way. Such as:

```
@articles = Article.where.not(id: list_of_already_fetched_ids).order("date_published DESC", "RANDOM()").paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10)
```

**NOTE:** `where.not` is usable in Rails 4, if you are not using Rails 4 you'll need to find another way to implement that filter.